# Synchronizing on System.out

Tags: java, file, synchronization

I changed `System.out` to print to a file, by invoking `System.setOut` and `System.setErr`.

Every night at midnight, we want to rename (archive) the current log file, and create a new one.

```
if (out != null) {
    out.close();
    out = null;
    File f = new File(outputfilename);
    f.renameTo(new File(dir.getPath().replace(".log", "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".log")))
    StartLogFile();
}
```

The `StartLogFile()`:

```
if (out == null) {
    out = new FileOutputStream(outputfilename, true);
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(out));
}
```

I've left exception-handling out.

My concern is that if something tries to print in between `out.close()` and `setOut`/`setErr` that I'm going to miss a log.

My real question is, how can I make this atomic with other calls to `System.out.println`? 
I was thinking about trying

```
synchronized (System.out) {

}
```

but I'm not actually sure if the intrinsic lock here does anything. Especially since I'm nullifying the out object during the operation.

Does anyone know how I can ensure proper synchronization here?

Comment: Not sure if this will be the solution for you, but one way would be to direct all log messages through a pipe before outputting them to a file, the pipe would have a way to stack messages in queue. Then when you need to rename the file, you close off the pipe end that outputs to file, rename your file and re-open the pipe under a new file with the new name, then any messages still in the pipe pour into the new file.

Comment: @CeilingGecko I thought about a solution similar to this. Frankly it would be too much work. The chance of this even being relevant is essentially 0. I figured I may as well ask as there may be a simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can achieve proper synchronization that way. Here is a sample test.

```
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {

    new Thread(()->{
        while(true){
            System.out.println("printing something");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }
    }).start();

    Thread.sleep(500);
    synchronized (System.out){
        System.out.println("changin system out");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("finished with sysout");
    }
    Thread.sleep(2000);
}
```

and the output will be:

```
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
changin system out
finished with sysout
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
printing something
```

Comment: ofcourse you need to create your new output stream outside the synchronized block and only put the code that actually is modifying that object...

Comment: I tweaked your example to properly handle an `InterruptedException` by re-interrupting the thread and exiting the loop, rather than printing and suppressing it.

Answer (score 5):

I would create the new out before closing the old one:

```
PrintStream old = System.out;
out = new FileOutputStream(outputfilename, true);
System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
old.close();
```

This way the old `PrintStream` is not closed until the new one is created and assigned. At all times there is a valid `PrintStream` in System.out.

There is no need for `synchronized` block, because everything is in the same thread.

Comment: What happens if something is written to `old` before the `setOut` is called. can you please explain?

Comment: This appears promising. Is `setOut` atomic?

Comment: @Cruncher This is a correct approach. The `PrintStream` class is correctly handling the _closing_ state. Internally, a print stream synchronizes on `this`.

Comment: Not sure about that. Probably not. There could be a race condition between calling `setOut` in one thread and resolving `System.out` in another. No matter how you call setOut, that would require synchronizing **all** `System.out` calls. Also the example given by @Durandal is a good example of an issue that could occur.

Comment: the solution to the issue pointed by @Durandal would be to implement your own `PrintStream` so that you could change its target on the fly, in a synchronized fashion. (Replace the internal writer by one pointing on a different file)

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem as easy to implement as I was expecting. Since the System.out has to point to the same filename as the old one was. Which means I have to close the printstream to rename it first

Comment: Ah! I now see another problem. First I thought that the only problem might be a write to the _old_ file while the switching is in progress (which would be acceptable). Btw: Setting fields is atomic. However, the problem is indeed a race condition: Reading `System.out` ... thread switch ... closing the stream, setting a new print stream to `System.out` ... thread switch ... writing to the _old_ print stream that now is closed ... ouch! In fact, that makes your answer wrong. :-)

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose: yes, that was the point of my comment, there is indeed a possible race, and the @Durandal's answer only make it more obvious. As for atomicity of field setting, some implementations of `setOut` are native, and I have not looked at the exact implementation (I would guess it is in fact atomic, though).

Comment: @Cruncher: I see why that would be a problem. however, considering that you need to close the stream to rename it before opening the new means you need to block all logs during this operation, which means you need to synchronize all the calls to System.out on a common lock.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to make this work *safely*, since you have *no control* what the calling code is doing with System.out. Think of this:

```
public void doSomethingTakingALongTime(PrintStream target) {
    // lots of code
}

// somewhere else
doSomethingTakingALongTime(System.out);
```

You can *never* be sure there isn't a copy of System.out reference somewhere out there in a local variable or method parameter.

The proper way to solve this would be to set System.out only *once*, at the very start of the program, and instead of using a standard PrintStream, you use your own implementation that delegates everything to the current target.

You are then in complete control of every output made through System.out and can synchronize at you leisure where required. If your own implementation synchronizes every operation, the question of what happens while you're changing the logging target doesn't even arise - every other caller will simply be blocked by the synchronization lock.

Btw. its questionable to use System.out for logging. The de-facto standard for logging would be using log4j. Consider switching to that.

Edit: Actually implementing this delegation can be rather *easy*. There is a constructor PrintStream(OutputStream). That means you can just implement delegation in an OutputStream (that has considerably less methods than PrintStream) and set System.out to your new PrintStream(YourRetargettingOutputStream).

Comment: This is good. I'll consider it. It does seem like a lot of work though. PrintStream has a lot of methods

Comment: Very good answer. +1 for suggesting an own sub class implementing the _rollover_ needs and for arguing against using `System.out`.

Comment: Good point. (A simple extension of PrintStream using reflection to switch the bufferedWriter can be considered, although to be tested, as it is not very safe.)

Comment: The Retargeting Output Stream would simply have to be synchronized to allow setting a new target without perturbing the write process. Any block synchronized on it would delay any write, allowing the file switch.

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, exactly as njzk2 comments. Since OutputStream's API consists only of 5 methods its not all that much work.

Answer (score 1):

You can define an object explicitly for locking like

```
static final Object lock = new Object();
```

How about locking over it like below

```
synchronized(lock){
    if(out != null) {
        out.close();
        out = null;
        File f = new File(outputfilename);
        f.renameTo(new File(dir.getPath().replace(".log", "-" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".log")))
        StartLogFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: This would require me to use this lock around every time I print something.

Comment: you would indeed need to synchronize every use (even in third party code pieces) of System.out.